# Customize ImageField url/path

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Page model that basically describes an HTML page. Pages are then served with URLs, such as http://www.mysite.com/page/1234/ for the page of id (pk) 1234.

I want to be able to add or attach images to my page. Therefore, I would like to use an Image class with a foreign key to a Page object:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = ...
    content = ...

class Image(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    image = models.ImageField(...)
```

Here is my problem: I would like to deliver images to the client with urls of the form:
http://www.mysite.com/images/1234/image_name.jpg, i.e a URL that includes the page id. Also on the server, the paths should reflect the page structure: /path/to/media/images/1234/image_name.jpg

I don't know how to tackle this problem. On one hand, I would like to keep the features of an ImageField related to path formatting. For example when uploading two images with the same name, Django creates two paths ending with "image.jpg" and "image_2.jpg" or so to make the difference between both images.

On the other hand, the upload_to option has limited capability, and I don't know how to insert the page id in the path. Especially, some tricky cases such as uploading an image at the same time a page is created (using the same form), which means a page id should be generated before uploading the image.

Is it reasonably easy to make an image model that would behave as described above? If so, how do I have to modify the Image model to insert the page id in the image path?

I have seen the question [Customize save path for ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659113/customize-save-path-for-imagefield), but it does not address the problem of primary key that might not be assigned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, a simple function passed as an upload_to parameter works, and there is no problem of non-existing id. So I guess that Django's default behaviour saves the image after saving the parent page model, as I wanted to.

In the Image model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

with the following function:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return 'pics/' + str(instance.page.id) + '/' + filename
```